# My Epson L1300 Feeds all the paper loaded into the tray

Tags: inkjet-printer

I replaced my upper roller Rubbers and the bottom feeder with new ones because the old ones gave up, but after this fix it feeds all the paper loaded into the tray. I did replace the springs that came with the feeder but i don't think it's the problem. How Should I Fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only assume that you dislodged the paper feed sensor cable or somehow (howbeit unlikely) damaged the sensor when servicing the rollers.  Also, make sure the optical sensor has a clear shot at the paper passing over it.

It will look something like this:
[image]

Try re-seating the cable and look for obvious defects you might have caused while working on the dang deal.  If that doesn't work, try replacing it (9-10USD on eBay).  It is the only thing I can think of that might cause this behavior.

If I am wrong, the most you are out is like 10 bucks or so.  It is ok to curse my name at that point (I would).

If for some reason "something is up" with the data being sent to the printer, I would only be able to deduce that with reading the dump going to the printer and educating myself on it's format.  This cause is extremely improbable.